# How can I show tabs as spaces instead of ^I or CTRL-I?

Tags: tab-characters, list, listchars

I use `list` and `listchars` to show my whitespace, but the code style I adhere to uses tabs. Seeing `>` or `^I` for all of my tabs is nauseating.

How would I keep all of my existing list characters but with a blank tab character?

Comment: Note that setting a space as a tab means you won't be able to distinguish between spaces and tabs, or see tabs in other places (like inside a string, end of the line). It sort of defeats the purpose of `set list` ;-) Some other (smaller) character you may try: `·` (MIDDLE DOT),  `␣` (OPEN BOX) or `₋` (SUBSCRIPT MINUS). (I personally use: `set listchars=tab:!·`).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker correct. This is why I have a linter. :) Exclamation point might not be so bad, I suppose I could play around with them.

Comment: As a worthy note, I've actually ended up using a tiny arrow for my tabs. Not as intrusive. `›`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`'listchars'` takes two characters for `tab` so you can simply use two regular spaces:

```
set listchars=tab:\ \ ,trail:·,eol:¬,nbsp:_
```

Comment: Didn't know you could do `\ `, though it makes sense since you can search with them (`/\ `). I was trying `\s`, `' '`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out non-breaking spaces work just fine.

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2228012/510036), the utf-8 sequence is `"\xc2\xa0"`.

Since I'm on a mac, I simply did `echo -en "\xc2\xa0" | pbcopy` and then added them to my *.vimrc*:

```
set listchars=tab:[2p],...
```

where `[2p]` pasted the clipboard twice. The result ended up being

```
set listchars=tab:<nbsp><nbsp>,...
```

which correctly caused tabs to show up as simple whitespace.

Comment: That's a lot of trouble when you could do `set listchars=tab:\ \ ,...`.

Comment: @romainl then make an answer :)